# Exchange 2007: Can't as send an alternate smtp e-mail address

Tags: exchange-2007

Got a situation with a single Exchange 2007 server, but happens with all users I try.

I've added a second public domain (also have a .local) to the "Accept Domains" field, and it's Authoritative. Let's say the domain is "MyDomain.com".

Then I added a SMTP address "userA@mydomain.com" to UserA's SMTP email address, but it's not his primary or "reply from" address, just another SMTP address. I also give UserA "Send As" permission to himself through EMC.

I open up their Outlook as UserA type in the From field "UserA@mydomain.com" and as soon as I hit send i get the famous "You do not have the permission to send the message on behalf of the specified user".

I did nothing with receipt policy. Do I need to?

This is a fresh install of Exchange 2007, not from 2000/2003/5.5.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created new mailboxes for the users and created POP accounts for them. This ended up having the most functionally for what I needed. The pop accounts are configured to have their delivery location a separate folder in the users inbox (Outlook 2007). With Outlook 2003, you can do this with "to" rules

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing won't do what you want. Adding a secondary SMTP proxy on a user won't cause that user to be able to send email that shows as coming "From:" that secondary address.

To do what you want you need to create a group object with the desired "secondary address" and grant the user "Send As" rights on the group object. Make the user a member of the group.

In order for the group to be able to receive replies from the Internet, modify the properties of the group by going to the "Mail Flow Settings" tab of the group properties and the "Properties" for "Message delivery restrictions". Uncheck the box "Require that all senders are authenticated".

Edit: Because I'm an idiot, I was only thinking about sending. I modified the above such that a group is used and, because the user is a member of the group, replies will be sent to the user.

Comment: Ok! Let me give it a try!

Comment: Won't any replies go to the folder/group/whatever, rather than the user?

Comment: Edit: I should've said "group" and not "contact" or "folder". It seems silly, but I really didn't think about replies-- I was focused on "Send As".

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you've got an internal SMTP receive connector on your Exchange box, setting an extra SMTP account up in that user's mail profile will do the job.  Just specify the appropriate 'from' address, and enter a dummy POP server so the user doesn't get two copies of all their mail.  They'll get an extra drop-down box in the 'new mail' dialog that will let them choose which account to send from.